# モデルのvalidation時に、関連のある別モデルも参照するやり方

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, バリデーション

Ruby on Railsのモデルにおけるvalidationを実装したいと考えています。

下記の`Applicant`モデルの保存時に、`Applicant`モデルと関連する`Target`モデル内のカラムも参照して重複排除したいと考えています。
1つのモデル内であれば、scopeを用いることで複数のカラムを参照した重複排除は可能だと思いますが、別モデルの値も参照した重複排除にするにはどうするのが良いか、伺えればと思います。

下記詳細となります。

---

## モデルの構成

[Event] --1:多-- [Target] --1:多-- [Applicant] --多:1-- [User]

---

## モデル：Applicant

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :target
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :event, through: :target
  # ここで、Applicantのカラム「user_id」とTargetのカラム「event_id」で
  # 重複をチエックしたいと考えています。
end
```

Applicantモデルのカラム：user_id,target_id,name等

---

## モデル：Target

```
class Target < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :applicants
end
```

Targetモデルのカラム：event_id,name等

---

## モデル：Event

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :targets
  has_many :applicants, through: :targets
end
```

Eventモデルのカラム：name等

---

もしくは、上記のようなものを実装したいのであれば、
`Applicant`モデルに「event_id」カラムを追加する方がよろしいでしょうか。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

標準のバリデータでは検証できないと思うので、カスタムバリデータを実装することになります。

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :custom_validate

  def custom_validate
    # 検証に失敗した場合
    errors.add(:column_name, "メッセージ")
  end
```

が、この例であれば、`Applicant`に`event_id`を持たせたほうが良いと思います。

関連先の値で検証を行う場合、カスタムバリデータの実装と関連先のモデルの作り方や作る順番に注意しないと、意図せず検証を通過してしまうことがあります。

Comment: 詳細にご教授いただきありがとうございます、`event_id` を `Applicant`に追加する形で対応したいと思います。